# Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null in " JSF2.0 " project

Tags: jsf, cdi

Im in JSF2.0 project in which I use a xhtml page with a CDI Bean ( @Named, @viewScoped as annotation). When i want to save a form inside this xhtml page I got this

> javax.servlet.ServletException: objectType.xhtml @33,65
>   value="#{beanController.object.serialNumber}": Target Unreachable,
>   'null' returned null  JSF2.0  .

a sample of code here to explain more

```
<h:form id="form1"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">
        <h:outputLabel for="id1" value=" serialNumber" />

        <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{beanController.object.serialNumber}">
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message for="id1" style="color:red" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

In the controller I declared and initialized the object ' object ' like `Object object = new Object();`

Please how could I report this issue ?

Regards

Comment: The error is most likely in the bean, but you posted no code. If you use `#{beanController.object.serialNumber}` there has to be a getter `int getSerialNumber()` and a setter `setSerialNumber(int n)`. The Object in java doesn't have these methods.

Comment: `null beanController` returned  a `null object` hence a `null returned null`. This means that the bean `beanController` is not appropriately annotated or could not have been loaded due to some errors. (wildfly sometimes simply says: `not loading bean definition due to some missing dependencies` in some special cases.